# Cannot connect to MySQL server through browser

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I am able to connect at CLI with:

```
mysql -h localhost -u username -p password
```

However, when I attempt to connect using PHP, nothing happens, and no error message is logged to `mysql.log`.

My script:

```
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "username"; $password = "password";
echo $password;
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

When I open the file containing this script, only `$password` is reported. Nothing else.

Any suggestions? I have uninstalled and re-installed MySQL several times with no success.

Comment: Did your $conn variable is instanced with mysqli_connect()?

Comment: Anything from error reporting? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: placed : "error_reporting(-1);" in script ; same response. only $password is reported. no error reported either in mysql_error.log or mysql.log

Comment: What do you mean, "only $password is reported"?

Comment: second line of my script contains echo $password. inserted in order to determine that php is functioning. and indeed the echo works. but nothing else.

Comment: Have you checked your server error log to see if there are any errors there?

Comment: [Mon May 11 11:10:31.724412 2020] [php7:error] [pid 3440] [client 127.0.0.1:33548] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /websites/test.php:9\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in test.php on line 9

Comment: based on server error noted above, I uncommented "extension=mysqli" in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini, then stopped and restarted mysql and apache2. seems to be working now. Thanks aynber, for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

based on fatal php error reported in apache2 error log, I uncommented "extension=mysqli" in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini, then stopped and restarted mysql and apache2.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password";
$database = "databasename";

// Create connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

*edited

You have to specify the databasename which you want to use.

Comment: *"You have to specify the databasename which you want to use."* - No they don't. They only need to connect to a database if they are to query and they haven't shown us that.

Comment: A database name on the connection is optional.

Comment: specified database. no change in response. "show databases" at mysql cli indicates database exists.